the calculate space around the div is not right with the metric where i have learned
four div with width 125 px without margin and padding physical align in a div with width 500 px without margin and padding   but i can do this with margin -2px in small box else with the code  over and give at big box 12 px more maybe you can help me why do not this


.box {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 512px;
  width: 512px;
}

.sm_box {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background: orange;
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
}
<div class="box">
  <div class="sm_box"></div>
  <div class="sm_box"></div>
  <div class="sm_box"></div>
  <div class="sm_box"></div>
  <div class="sm_box"></div>
  <div class="sm_box"></div>
  <div class="sm_box"></div>
  <div class="sm_box"></div>
  <div class="sm_box"></div>
  <div class="sm_box"></div>
  <div class="sm_box"></div>
  <div class="sm_box"></div>
  <div class="sm_box"></div>
  <div class="sm_box"></div>
  <div class="sm_box"></div>
  <div class="sm_box"></div>
</div>




.box{
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
height:500x;
width:503px;
font-size:0;
}
.sm_box{
margin: 0;
padding:0;
display:inline-block;
background:orange;
height:125px;
width:125px;
font-size:0;
border-left:0.1px solid black;
